# pexpect output in 3.4 not as intended has some \b\n values. Works well with 2.7 though

Tags: python, ssh, python-3.4, pexpect

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = input('hostname: ')
    username = input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('uptime')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    print(s.before)        # print everything before the prompt.
    s.sendline('ls -l')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.sendline('df')
    s.prompt()
    print(s.before)
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```

below is the o/p:

```
b'uptime\r\n 22:27:16 up 45 min,  4 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.05, 0.00\r\n'
b'ls -l\r\ntotal 60\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Mar  3 16:25 \x1b[0m\x1b[01;34mDesktop\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 6 pi pi 4096 Apr  5 13:13 \x1b[01;34mDocuments\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 Apr 13 05:51 \x1b[01;34mDownloads\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Mar  3 16:25 \x1b[01;34mMusic\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 Jun 14 15:00 \x1b[01;34moldconffiles\x1b[0m\r\n-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  592 Jun 23 22:26 pexpected_ssh.py\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 4 pi pi 4096 Apr 13 06:55 \x1b[01;34mphantomjs-on-raspberry\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Mar  3 16:25 \x1b[01;34mPictures\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Mar  3 16:25 \x1b[01;34mPublic\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 6 pi pi 4096 Apr 17 20:30 \x1b[01;34mPytest1\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 11 21:56 \x1b[01;34mpython1\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Mar  3 15:55 \x1b[01;34mpython_games\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Mar  3 16:25 \x1b[01;34mTemplates\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Apr 11 14:57 \x1b[01;34mtest\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi 4096 Mar  3 16:25 \x1b[01;34mVideos\x1b[0m\r\n'
b'df\r\nFilesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on\r\n/dev/root       29710268 6264956  22178580  23% /\r\ndevtmpfs          468148       0    468148   0% /dev\r\ntmpfs             472756       0    472756   0% /dev/shm\r\ntmpfs             472756    6504    466252   2% /run\r\ntmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock\r\ntmpfs             472756       0    472756   0% /sys/fs/cgroup\r\n/dev/mmcblk0p1     63503   21390     42113  34% /boot\r\ntmpfs              94552       0     94552   0% /run/user/1000\r\n/dev/sda1       15289328 2940992  12348336  20% /media/pi/SHUBHAYAN1\r\n'
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python 3.x the `s.before` is of `bytes` instead of `str`. You need to convert from `bytes` to `str`:

```
v = s.before.decode()
print(v)
```

---

The default *encoding* for `decode()` is `utf-8`. You need to specify the correct *encoding* if it's not in `utf-8`. E.g.:

```
v = s.before.decode(encoding='latin1')
```

See Python3's [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) for more details.